# Check a query exists in multiple tables

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple tables like this

```
Table P(x,y)      Table Q(x, y)     Table R(x)      Table T(x)    
x   y                  x    y              x               x       
0   1                  1    0              0               0       
0   2                  2    1              1               1        
1   2                                      3               2       
                                                           3
```

How do I check if there exists ONE x1,y1,x2,y2 satisfies P(x1, y1) ^ R(x1) ^ T(x2) ^ P(x2, y2) in all the above multiple tables in python?

Comment: `T(x3)` seems to be independent of the others, is that the case?

Comment: @Graipher Yes, the variables in each table could share or not share in common

Comment: Well, that edit completely changes the question and invalidates my answer...

Answer (score 0):

you could do in one query. you have to create the query in yout Pyhon progarm and replace X1,X2,Y1,Y2 with the parameter

```
select 
ifNUll((select true from P where x=X1 and y=Y1),False)
and
ifNUll((select true from Q where y=Y1 and x=X2),False)
and
ifNUll((select true from R where x=X1),False)
and
ifNUll((select true from T where x=X2),False)
as 
ConditionFound
```